# I have the following xml that come as http request body. How can I map it to a java object?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

This is the xml that I have from http request body. so how can I map it to a java object?  Your help with a code example is highly appreciated.

```
 <search version="1.0">
        <sessionid>3398392</sessionid>
        <auth></auth>
        <usertype>provider</usertype>
            <param type="age">21</param>
            <param type="sex">Male</param>
            <param type="MRN">12345</param>
            <param type="CSN">123456789</param>
            <param type="Name">LastName,FirstName</param>
            <param type="Sex">2</param>
            <param type="AgeDays">7805</param>
            <param type="WeightKg">99</param>
            <param type="HeightCm">180</param>
            <param type="BMI">30.56</param>
            <param type="BSA">2.22</param>
            <param type="LastOrder">{
                        "Duration":24,
                        "DurationUnit":"Hours",
                        "Frequency":"continuous",
                        "InfusionSite":"Central",
                        "LockDosingFields":"YES",
                        "MixtureComponents":[{
                                                "ComponentName":"AminoAcid", 
                                                "Dose":1.2,"DoseUnit":"g/kg"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "ComponentName":"Dextrose", 
                                                "Dose":200,"DoseUnit":"g"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "ComponentName":"EMULSION", 
                                                "Dose":500, "DoseUnit":"mL", 
                                                "Frequency":200905
                                            }],
                        "ORDERKEY":"3-IN-1",
                        "Volume":1440,
                        "Weight":99,
                        "WeightUnit":"kg"
                        }
            </param>
    </search>
```

I am using spring. so I have the following method in my controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/calculator", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView calculatorHome(@RequestBody PatientSearch patientXml){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            modelAndView.addObject("myJSONObject", 
                  mapper.writeValueAsString(patientXml.getParam()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName(CALCULATOR);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Here is my PatientSearch classe:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "search", propOrder = {
            "sessionid",
            "auth",
            "usertype",
            "param"
    })
    public class PatientSearch implements Serializable{
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        private String auth;
        private String sessionid;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        private String usertype;
        protected List<PatientSearchParam> param;
    //getters and setters
    }
```

Here is my PatientSearchParam class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "param", propOrder = {
        "value"
})
public class PatientSearchParam implements Serializable {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You can use JAXB, the Java XML-to-object binding API, or parse the XML using a DOM parser and map it into an object manually.  If you're using Spring Boot you can ask Spring to map to an object model based on MIME type (JSON, XML, etc.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Should each `<param>` correspond to some Java property of a class representing `<search>`? Should it be turned into a `Map<String, Object>`? What do you want done with that nested JSON in the LastOrder param? As it stands the question is too broad to provide an accurate answer. Start by looking into JAXB.

Comment: The main goal is after converting the xml to a java object, and map that java object  to a jsonObject and finally I want to access it in javascrip by adding it into spring ModelAndView. Here is my code snap

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/calculator", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView calculatorHome(@RequestBody PatientSearch patientXml){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            modelAndView.addObject("myJSONObject", mapper.writeValueAsString(patientXml.getParam()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName(CALCULATOR);
        return modelAndView;
    }

Comment: @G_H  Sorry I am new to such kind of implementation. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @G_H I have included the code. Can you please look at it and let me know what should I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: @duffymo can you check my implementation above and give your suggestion?

Comment: If you want JSON, why wouldn't you go directly from HTTP to JSON?  Spring Boot makes this easy.  Response MIME type should be chosen by the user.  Can users choose between JSON, XML, etc.?  They should.

Comment: @duffymo I am providing the service and the client will send me xml embedded in http request body.